# In an IF statement in PHP with OR, how to track which condition evaluated false?

Tags: php, codeigniter

for example, in PHP code like this:

```
if($this->function1() && $this->function2())
{
  //everything is alright
}
else
{
  //function1 or function2 returned false
  //whodunnit?
}
```

Is there a language construct or something that can help me find out the culprit in the **else** block? I don't want to have to run the conditions once again, just to find out what went wrong.

Please bear with my pseudo-code. My actual code will look totally out-of-context here... and I'm using CodeIgniter, by the way.

Comment: Good testcase, good question. You stripped it down properly.

Comment: I'm such a slave to praise. Thanks for the warm fuzzy feelings this early in the morning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use the name of the function that caused the error.

This is somewhat ugly. I wouldn't use it (= "for this purpose").
Also I'm making this CW to eschew the downvotes.

```
 if ($this->function1($failed="func1") && $this->function2(.., $failed="func2")) {
    ...
 }
 else {
    print $failed;
```

This syntactic workaround necessitates that you *can* fill up the methods parameters with the required number and pass the fake `$failed` parameter in an unused spot. It in fact just adds this variable to the local variable scope.

You could redesign this if-statement more clumsily with more && ands and () parens to the same effect. This is just somewhat compacter. Yet I'm not sure if I understand why you would want a string with the failed function name, not just a boolean, or what's up with the `if`phobia.

Comment: I see why you made this community wiki... LOL ;) (not going to -1 anyway)

Comment: Now that I think about it, not sure if this shortuct works at all.

Comment: ahahahahah I can't not leave a -1 now XD

Comment: Oh interesting. Function calls hold proper sub-expressions. I would upvote myself.

Comment: @mario: If I was you I wouldn't. Your first solution with `$f` is much more cleaner. I can't imagine how much time can take that to be understand by a future developer there

Comment: @mario Thanks for the "community wiki"... I'll hopefully see more answers like yours with esoteric (in a positive way, mind) code that can show me some dancing-monkey PHP tricks :D I'mma check out what you suggested and report back here with the results, 'soon'.

Comment: @mario I want the failed function name so that I can stuff it into the Session as a key with a false value. I'm using this value in my View (as in MVC) to decide error message output.

Comment: @mario all my life, I've used nestednestednested *if* blocks. After converting to CodeIgniter, I have to come to love my form processing code blocks more, because they look so clean thanks to the form_validation library. I could simply extend this library for my project, actually, and use the same _sexy_ syntax, but I wanted to know what PHP can do. @yes123 I like leaving lovely, murderous-hate-inducing puzzles for future developers, isn't that all we do? Solving puzzles? :D

Comment: @aditya: i guess you have to wait tomorrow mario's sleeping now

Comment: @yes123 I guessed as much, but sorry, I can't resist editing to make my comment sound better. I hope I didn't inundate your inbox with updates. Blame StackOverflow for providing so much functionality, not me for using it! :P

Comment: @aditya: You could use the temporary boolean variables likewise. A simple `$_SESSION['failedfunc'][$f1 ? "func2" : "func1"] = false;` with the first appraoch might be saner. But seeing that they represent a status the storage as a string is understandable. As alternative you could of course define a wrapper function `onfalse(func1(), &$failed, "func1")` and use that in your `if` parts. That's not more readable IMO, but maybe easier to follow for others.

Comment: @mario In the first approach, it's not an either-or scenario. What you demonstrated is _cool!_ (very cool actually), I'm probably going to go with that, but sometimes, func2 and func1 might both evaluate to false... what to do then? Right now, I'm going to ignore it because the script is already stopping at ONE false, but in the future, this hamletian dilemma might come up again. I don't understand the second one fully - I think got the gist, but can you please provide more details implementing that?

Comment: @aditya: If you need to evaluate all conditions (not the short-circuit `if &&`) then I would eventually use an `array("func1" => func1(), "func2" => func2())` to hold all conditions in another temporary variable. But then the `if` would get bloated... -- The wrapper function `onfalse` can be implemented in multiple ways. In my imagined example it just checks the boolean result it receives and returns it 1:1 (for use in the outer `if`), but it also sets the reference & variable parameter if a condition (=false) is met.

Answer (score 8):

```
if($this->function1()) {
    if($this->function2()) {
        // both worked
    } else {
        // function1 returned a true value
        // function2 returned a false value
    }
} else {
    // function1 returned a false value
    // (you could optionally call $this->function2() here)
}
```

or, if you always want to run both functions:

```
$result1 = $this->function1();
$result2 = $this->function2();
if($result1 && $result2) {
    // everything is okay
} else {
    // look at the results to figure out what to do
}
```

or, if you want to do the first but without 2 levels of indentation:

```
if(!$this->function1()) {
    // function1 returned false
    // (you can call $this->function2() here if you want)
} elseif (!$this->function2()) {
    // function2 returned false
} else {
    // everything is okay
}
```

Comment: +1 for elegant solution (not needing any additional space for variables)

Comment: I certainly wouldn't call it "elegant", but that's not Amber's fault. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like to avoid nesting IF statements. The indentation gets too much with each level of sinking in...

In the second solution, we are talking about *again* checking $result1 and $result2 in an if-statement (together or separately in two lines)... is there no way to avoid that?

Comment: @aditya: There's nothing built into the syntax of the language (or, indeed, of any C-style language), no. You can hack around it with variables as mentioned here and in other answers.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal *sigh* okay. :(

Comment: @aditya see the third option I edited in for a way to do this with only 1 indentation level.

Comment: This third option does the job too, it's actually the best way to use if I want future devs to keep their hair, even if it still doesn't fully meet my goal of doing away with more than 1 if structure in this scenario. But I've already accepted Mario's answer... hope you don't mind. I really wish I could accept more than one :(

Answer (score 1):

Most trivial solution: store the results of both functions in variables and check them in your if-condition.

Comment: Robert, please check my comments on similar answers above when you get the time, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    functionA();
    functionB();
}catch(YourExceptionType $e){
    //use $e to know what, where, and why it happened
}
```

That's what I would do

and if you are not throwing exceptions you may use "or", because when function is true then the second part of the or will never be run:

```
functionA() or somethingWentWrong();
functionB() or somethingWentWrong();
```

but I still recoment try/catch

Comment: Thank you for that SparK. I really like the second solution for it's superb readability. try/catch is also a great suggestion. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary variables in the `if` itself:

```
if ($f1=$this->function1() and $f2=$this->function2()) {
```

Then later check them.

Note that I replaced `&&` with `and` to avoid extra parenthesis ([the `and` has lower precedence than the assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)).

Comment: @mario: Regarding your last paragraph, that's highly error-prone and not self-documenting at all. Put the parentheses in.

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer... but is there nothing built in to PHP (I'm not insisting that there _should_ be, the PHP architects are obviously thousands of light years away from my level of knowledge), that can simply track and tell me who, $f1 or $f2, caused the 'false' evaluation - without having to write more if-statements?

Comment: @aditya menon: Well. How do you want to utilize that information? And how do you want it to be present if not in form of a variable?

Comment: @aditya: I wouldn't praise the PHP architects too much.

Comment: @mario I want to use the name of the function that caused the error. Currently, I'm nesting the if-evaluations of two very similarly named functions, and then I'm writing something into a session (with the same name as that of the function) when any one of them evaluate to false.

If I find out which function evaluated to false and get it's name in a string, I can do it in one line...

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Well, they're responsible in a very indirect way for the food on my table for the past 5 years. So their non-support of multiple inheritance and 'Cannot use variable in write context' errors are forgiven :)

Comment: @aditya: A slippery slope, my friend!

Comment: @aditya: you can't do that without an additional if

Comment: @mario: I bet `&&` has the same precedence than `and`. temporany -1 awaiting details

Comment: @yes123: You could have just looked at [the documentation on PHP operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), in seconds. I sure wish I could -1 a comment.